# Javascript function is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hi");   

    function search() { 
        var title=$("#search").val(); 
        $("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"ajax_search-process.php",
            data:"title="+title,
            success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
                $("#search").val("");
            }
        });
    }

    $("#button").click(function(){
        search();
    });

    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            search();
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Search" onclick="search()" />
```

Hi friends in the above code, I would like to call search function but if I used the function the `$(document).ready(function(){...}` is not alerting the alert value and the function is also not fired. But when I removed the function the alert function is working. Can any one help me out how we can achieve to call the search function.

Comment: you not need in inline handler `onclick="search()"` because you anyway add it with jquery

Comment: @felix-kling question is not duplicate, the issue is just a syntax error using quotes.